# Updated Drupal via Drush up command. Now I have a Server 500 error

Tags: drupal, chmod, chown, drush

I have a Drupal install on my local machine. Ran Drush up command to update the core files. Now I just get a Server 500 error. Before I ran drush up, my drupal installation folders permissions looked like:

```
drwxr-xr-x  27 uName staff 918 ...
```

After running drush up, they look like this:

```
drwxr-xr-x  29 uName staff 986 ....
```

I admit I am not extremely familiar with chmod/chown or how to fix this issue, but I am sure it has something to do with the folder/file permissions. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you get to any pages on the site? e.g. can you access www.yoursite.com/admin but just not www.yoursite.com?

Comment: I cannot access anything. Using Mac Finder, I can see the directory and the folders, but when viewing my local sites in localhost on the browser, I cannot even see the directory.

Comment: I don't think it's a permissions issue, the folder is still owned by the same group and user. The second column there is number of [Hard Links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link) and the 5th is the size of the file/folder so it seems reasonable that both of those could have changed. What version of Drupal are you using?

Comment: I upgraded to the latest version, which I believe is 7.8 from the last version, 7.6 or 7.7. That upgrade would account for the change in file/directory size. So what else could cause the error? The folder doesn't even show up in the directory within localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting. A few things to try:

- Visit update.php on your site (if you can get there) and run through
  the updates, it's possible there are some lingering
- Run a `TRUNCATE TABLE cache` MySQL query, and repeat for all other
  tables whose name begin with `cache_`
- Move your .htaccess file out of the site root and try to access the site again. If it works you know the problem is in there
- Check that you didn't have any custom changes in the old .htaccess file; if you did, make sure tha changes are copied across to the new file (once you've moved it back into the site root).
- After that you're really left with manually disabling contributed modules in the `system` table (setting `status` column to 0) and visiting the site again after each; that way you might be able to narrow down a rogue contributed module that is now causing a problem.

Let me know how you get on with that, if none of it works there might be more things you can try.